# Testing the scope of a type with structureMap

Tags: c#, tdd, structuremap

How do I test the scope of a registered type with structureMap?

For instance I have a registry:

```
 public class DataRegistry : Registry
 {
    public DataRegistry()
    {
        ForRequestedType<ISessionManager>().TheDefaultIsConcreteType<SessionManager>().CacheBy(StructureMap.Attributes.InstanceScope.Singleton);
        ForRequestedType<ISessionRequest>().TheDefaultIsConcreteType<SessionRequest>().CacheBy(StructureMap.Attributes.InstanceScope.HttpContext);
    }
 }
```

And I want to test that ISessionRequest instance scope is HttpContext. So I have a test:

```
    [Test]
    public void Container_AlwaysHas_OneSessionRequestPerHTTPContext()
    {
        //Setup

        //Act
        ObjectFactory.Configure(r => r.AddRegistry<DataRegistry>());

        //Test
    }
```

But I don't know to test the scope of the type once it's registered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you wish to write a test proving that the lifecycle of a registered plugin has the desired lifecycle.

You can inspect the model of the container. Here is one of the tests you wish to write.

```
[TestFixture]
public class container_registration
{
    [Test]
    public void session_request_should_be_scopped_per_httpcontext()
    {
        var container = new Container(new DataRegistry());

        var plugin = container.Model.PluginTypes.First(p => p.PluginType.UnderlyingSystemType == typeof(ISessionRequest));

        plugin.Lifecycle.ShouldBeOfType(typeof(HttpContextLifecycle));
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks like it. Much obliged

Comment: Sorry it seems that LifeCycle is no longer a member of PluginTypeConfiguration... maybe it has been deprecated or renamed, any ideas? Cant seem to view the structuremap api docs either they're all garbled...

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I was using StructureMap's trunk could be this is a new property?

Answer (score 0):

```
[TestFixture]
public class WhenRegisteringItemsInTheIoc
{   
    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        Given_A_Ioc_Container();
        When_Registering_Items_In_The_Ioc();
    }
    private Container _container;

    private void Given_A_Ioc_Container()
    {
        _container = new Container();
    }

    public void When_Registering_Items_In_The_Ioc()
    {
        _container.Configure(registry => registry.For<IContext>().HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped().Use<Context>());
    }

    [Test]
    public void Then_Should_Have_A_LifeTime_Of_Hybrid_Http_Or_Thread_Local_Scoped()
    {
        IPluginTypeConfiguration plugin =
            _container.Model.PluginTypes.First(p => p.PluginType.UnderlyingSystemType == typeof (IContext));
        Assert.That(plugin.Lifecycle, Is.EqualTo("Hybrid"));
    }
}
```

In case anyone revisits this in the future, the above is a test  we are using to cover this scenario. "plugin.Lifecycle" returns a string relating to the scope, which in this case is "Hybrid". If no scope is defined "Transient" is returned.